# Child theme loses wp-admin styling

Tags: wp-admin, child-theme, visual-editor

I am new to Wordpress so I apologize if I use incorrect words while referring to things.

We are using the theme **smart-mag**. I created a child theme **smart-mag-child** which contains a `style.css` and `function.php` file.

The child theme's styles are working properly and importing the parent styles but I am losing the styling while in the editor.

The example below shows that I lost the font-family but it applies to more styling.

*The post editor for smart-mag theme*
[image: The post editor for smart-mag]

*The post editor for smart-mag-child theme*
[image: The post editor for smart-mag-child]

I know this isn't a huge deal but the styles matching will help our marketing team who actually edit the content overall.

How do I import the parent theme's styling for the editor/admin area?

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding this to my 'smart-mag-child' `functions.php` file worked.

`add_editor_style( get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );`

*If someone can show me documentation to how to properly do this that would be appreciated.*

Edit:
Dokumentation about this to understanding why it works.

- [`add_editor_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/) - Add callback for custom TinyMCE editor stylesheets.
- [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) - Retrieve theme directory URI. In the case a child theme is being used, the absolute path to the parent theme directory will be returned. Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to get the absolute path to the child theme directory.

Comment: Yes, this function is right for your goal to add the stylesheet to the editor. The function to get the template-directory is right, the stylesheet-directory should get the path to the child theme.

Comment: Really Welcome.